# PyGTK callback function not executing step by step

Tags: python, callback, gtk, pygtk

I'm new to Python and GTK. I'm trying to display a dialog box with some text which looks like a something is loading at the back. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk, gobject, time


class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        #Progress Bar
        self.button=gtk.Button("click")
        self.window.add(self.button)
        self.button.connect("clicked",self.display)
        self.dialog = gtk.Dialog()
        self.label = gtk.Label("Text")
        self.dialog.vbox.pack_start(self.label,True,True,0)
        self.label.show()
        self.window.show_all()

    def display(self,widget):
        self.dialog.show()
        for i in range(0,5):
            self.label.set_text("Text"+" . "*i)
            time.sleep(1)
        self.dialog.hide()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

print __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

I want to display text following with 4 dots(.) which appear after 1 second each.The problem I'm facing is when I click the button the dialog box appears after 5 seconds with all the 4 dots. Whats wrong with the code?
It would be great if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: The GTK 2.0/pyGTK combination is old... GTK 3 has been out for years and GTK 4 is showing up. If you're starting in GTK and python, read this tutorial for python and GTK 3: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep()`; use `glib.timeout_add()` instead. I'm not sure if that's the exact name PyGTK gives it.